# Excel export date formatting goes wrong, but only for some date values

Tags: excel, vb.net, datetime, ms-access, export-to-excel

I am formatting my datetime values into dates when exporting from access to excel, using vb.net.

I have got the following code

```
Dim formatRange As Excel.Range

formatRange = xlWorksheet.Range("C1", "C9999")
formatRange.NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

formatRange = xlWorksheet.Range("D1", "D9999")
formatRange.NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
```

This works for most dates in my database, however, some of them are still displaying with the time portion of 00:00:00, I think when the dates are higher than 20..

Why is this, and how do I fix it?

**EDIT**

My full code is:

```
Dim sPath As String = sDt.Rows(0).Item("excelPath")
Dim i, j As Integer

Dim xlapp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim misvalue As Object = Reflection.Missing.Value

xlapp = New Excel.Application
xlWorkbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Add(misvalue)
xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets.Add
xlWorksheet.Name = "CommissionInformation"

Dim formatRange As Excel.Range

formatRange = xlWorksheet.Range("C1", "C9999")
formatRange.NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

formatRange = xlWorksheet.Range("D1", "D9999")
formatRange.NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

For k As Integer = 1 To dgvExport.Columns.Count
     xlWorksheet.Cells(1, k) = dgvExport.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
Next

For i = 0 To dgvExport.RowCount - 1
  For j = 0 To dgvExport.ColumnCount - 1
       xlWorksheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = dgvExport(j, i).Value.ToString
  Next
Next

xlWorksheet.Columns.AutoFit()
```

Comment: Dates should nearly always be formatted to year/month/day, so yyyy/MM/dd

Comment: @Fionnuala Even for UK dates?

Comment: It sounds like you don't export the date values _as is_ but strings expressing the values.

Comment: @Gustav In my database they are saved as DateTime (And then being displayed in a DataGridView, from which the data is taken and exported

Comment: Yes, but your secret code may trap you.

Comment: @Gustav The full code is there now

Comment: Yes, all dates. It is important that dates should be explicit across all regions. Access will default to US dates given half a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As guessed, you export text:

```
   xlWorksheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = dgvExport(j, i).Value.ToString
```

That will force your default date format on your text expressions for the date values.

Date values carries no format. So insert the value:

```
   xlWorksheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = dgvExport(j, i).Value
```

Answer (score 1):

While it may be tempting to simply push the `.Value` from the DataGridView cell into the Excel cell as recommended in another answer ...

```vb
xlWorksheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = dgvExport(j, i).Value
```

... and that approach will work for current dates, it will also

1. introduce an off-by-one bug for dates prior to 1900-03-01, and
2. fail completely for dates prior to 1899-12-30.

A safer approach is to continue using `.ToString`, but force it to be an unambiguous yyyy-mm-dd date:

```vb
xlWorksheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = Convert.ToDateTime(dgvExport(j, i).Value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

That will ensure that the correct date *value* is inserted into the Excel cell, while the resulting date *format* will be applied by explicit cell formatting in Excel, or by the default formatting specified in the Regional Settings of the Windows Control Panel.

Comment: Hi Gord, this information is useful, and if the previous answer didn't solve the issue, then I'd use this method, however this system will never encounter dates prior to 2016, so the issue wont arise. If ever this may be the case in a different program, however, then I'll certainly consider this